# Is there any add-on supporting automatic texture assignment?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on

I'd like to know whether there is an add-on that automatically creates a texture setup.

There is [Poliigon Material Converter](https://help.poliigon.com/en/articles/2540839-poliigon-material-converter-addon-for-blender) which connects all textures to the *Principled BSDF* but that only works specifically for textures from [Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/). Also using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> hotkey from [Node Wrangler](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/node/node_wrangler.html)  is not working in my case.

**Q:** Is there any add-on which supports all textures regardless of any naming convention?

Comment: Node-wrangler addon doesn't necessarily  be accessed with hotkeys. You can do it manually by pressing N in the **Shader Editor** > select *node wrangler* > and click on *Add Pricipled setup* and select the textures you want

Comment: Would take a long time to classify all the different images automatically so using the name is lightweight and easy to determine whether it's a diffuse, normal or roughness texture. You would either have to create your own python script/add-on to create image nodes and assign the image to them based on the name or just re-name your image files according to the node wrangler docs. So please provide more context and especially how your textures are called...?

Comment: Since Blender 3.5 Node Wrangler is much better at matching: https://archive.blender.org/developer/D16940 If you'd provide an example of how Node Wrangler is failing that would make it much easier to comment on your question.